# Estadística. Muestreo sistemático

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

El problema que planteo consiste en, partiendo de un dataframe (df) con elementos de una población estadística, elegir elementos igualmente espaciados en el df, siendo el primero elegido al azar.

Para la simulación, disponemos del siguiente df.

```
# Ventas semanales
import numpy as np # importando numpy
import pandas as pd # importando pandas
data = np.array(
    [[65, 36, 49, 84, 79, 56, 28, 43, 67, 36],
       [43, 78, 37, 40, 68, 72, 55, 62, 22, 82],
       [88, 50, 60, 56, 57, 46, 39, 57, 73, 65],
       [59, 48, 76, 74, 70, 51, 40,  7, 56, 45],
       [35, 62, 52, 63, 32, 80, 64, 53, 74, 34],
       [76, 60, 48, 55, 51, 54, 45, 44, 35, 51],
       [21, 35, 61, 45, 33, 61, 77, 60, 85, 68],
       [45, 53, 34, 67, 42, 69, 52, 68, 52, 47],
       [62, 65, 55, 71, 73, 50, 53, 59, 41, 54],
       [41, 74, 82, 58, 26, 35, 47, 50, 38, 70]]
    )

pd.set_option('precision', 2)
# array de una lista.
datos_fila = data[:,:].flatten()
# Lista ordenada de datos
lista_ordenada = np.sort(datos_fila, axis=None)
# df de ventas
df_datos = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Crear un df de una única columna, con una lista
datos =  pd.DataFrame(lista_ordenada)  
datos.columns = (["Valores"])
datos[:3]
```

Con el siguiente script consigo hacer la selección.

```
muestra = []
N = datos_fila.shape[0]
tamaño_muestra = 5
contador = 0
intervalo =int (N/tamaño_muestra)
for i in range (0, datos_fila.shape[0]):
    elemento = muestra.append(datos_fila[i+intervalo])
    contador += 1
    if contador == tamaño_muestra:
        break
muestra
```

Con este código consigo seleccionar una muestra de elementos igualmente espaciados en el df, pero no cumplo el requisito de que el primero sea elegido al azar.

La pregunta que planteo es si se podría realizar este muestreo sistemático aplicando algún método.

Answer (score 1):

Existe un modulo llamado random que podrías usar.

puedes generar un numero aleatorio entre 0 y el tamaño de `datos_fila` así

```
N = random.randint(0, datos_fila.shape[0])
```

O elegir un elemento aleatorio de la lista con:

```
N = random.choice(datos_fila)
```